# Django 1.3.7 TemplateDoesNotExist error admin/index.html

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

There are numerous questions asked on this site similar to this one, but I couldn't find one that could explain this particular behavior.

I am relatively new to django and ubuntu, so maybe the explanation is simple.  This is an old (v1.3.7) django project I'm attempting to migrate to a new server.

Here is the full error I am getting in my apache log:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/
admin/login.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://131.212.123.7:26080/glrimon/admin/
Django Version: 1.3.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
admin/login.html
Exception Location: /.../leave_beave/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 138
Python Executable:  /.../leave_beave/bin/python
```

`leave_beave` is the name of my virtualenv.

Here is the info passed along by the traceback:

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/glri_mon/siteweb/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/glri_mon/siteweb/gps_upload/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/glri_mon/siteweb/siteapp/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/glri_mon/siteweb/glrimon_models/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/glri_mon/siteweb/sdde/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/glri_mon/siteweb/dv/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/glri_mon/siteweb/contains/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/glri_mon/siteweb/sqlwrite/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/.../leave_beave/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/.../leave_beave/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tinymce/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/.../leave_beave/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mptt/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/.../leave_beave/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menus/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/.../leave_beave/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/plugins/text/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/.../leave_beave/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/plugins/picture/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/.../leave_beave/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/plugins/link/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/.../leave_beave/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/plugins/file/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/.../leave_beave/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/plugins/snippet/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
/glri_mon/siteweb/cmsplugin_rst/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
```

`glri_mon` is the django project directory.
Here's the path to the template in question: `/.../leave_beave/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html`. Any thoughts on why django didn't include that path in it's search?

Here are my template loaders from settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

I received this same error for an earlier problem, and I solved it by creating a symlink from the templates directory in question (`.../python2.7/site-packages/lib.../package/templates`) to my `/project_dir/templates` directory, which is the one configured as my template directory in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PATH, 'templates'),
)
```

I did this at the time, since I thought it was a one-off hack solution sort of thing, but now I'm getting the same error for attempting to access the admin page of my site (http://.../admin/).  This tells me I'm going about this wrong.

I suppose I could add a symlink to every template directory that generates this error, but that doesn't seem like a good idea for a production site.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have `django.contrib.admin` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: I do indeed. Thanks for checking.

Comment: Since you are running in Apache, you will need to setup static files.  Have you done so?

Comment: The static files all load correctly for at least one of the apps under this django project. Should I post my apache config? Could it be something in there?

Comment: You absolutely definitely should not be using Django 1.3.

Comment: I don't have much choice here; an upgrade to django would likely mean an upgrade to all of the project dependencies.

Comment: @Dashdrum static files have nothing to do with templates.

Comment: You say that the template in question is under `/.../leave_beave/django`. This is strange, shouldn't it be under `/.../leave_beave/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django`?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides- That's the arrangement I would expect.  Indeed in `.../django/contrib/admin/sites.py` under `index()` this is the return:    `return render_to_response(self.index_template or 'admin/index.html', context, context_instance=context_instance)`, so I would expect there to be an admin templates folder on that same level.

Answer (score 11):

Newer versions of pip will create a wheel for the package, to speed up installation for the next time you use it. However because of this the templates are being installed into the virtual environment root directory.

A workaround to disable wheel creation was added to 1.4.22 - https://github.com/django/django/commit/3b324970e390a6dc4c373db036d6f27300d7fded, however anything before that would've created wheel files which cause problems such as missing templates.

Official support for wheel files was added to 1.5.1 - https://github.com/django/django/commit/4391718f26466f82f943e37368181d5c0520fa35.

With pip version 19, you can skip wheel installation/creation with `pip install --no-binary Django Django==1.3.7`. Older versions of pip may have slightly different command line arguments.

Answer (score 4):

In the interest of completeness, I solved this issue by explicitly adding the path to the `/admin` templates to TEMPLATE_DIRS in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PATH, 'templates'),
    "/.../leave_beave/django/contrib/admin/templates",
)
```

I doubt this was the intended way of going about this for django 1.3 but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that Django is unable to search for admin templates! 
Probably, it may be the case `/.../leave_beave/django/contrib/admin/templates` directory is missing. But chances of this are minimal.

If that not the case and if you are using **Django 1.8+**, then you need to revisit Templates's setting in your project settings. Make sure you have defined `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` and `TEMPLATES` properly.

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
)
```

These are the default loader of Django and need not be explicitly defined.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

In the `TEMPLATES` settings to need to check if a value of `APP_DIRS` is set to be  `True`. If this value is set as `False` Django won't be able to look for app level templates. So, won't be able to discover admin templates.